# how to put title on left side and command-link on right side of a pageblock-section header

Tags: apex, visualforce

all i have requirement where i need to show tittle along with command link in apex:pageblocksection....same as in when we create account record it shows in address information section one side tittle and another side command link ..

i am not able to call a function from my controller here is my controller

```
public PageReference copy_billingto_shipping() { 
    System.debug('In function'); 
    if(this.acct.BillingStreet != null) { 
        System.debug('In if condition'); 
        this.acct.ShippingStreet = this.acct.BillingStreet; 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

here is vf page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="Account_OverrideCtrl" tabstyle="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock mode="edit" id="AccountPB" title="Account Edit">
            <apex:pageblockbuttons>
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="Save"></apex:commandbutton>
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"></apex:commandbutton>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
<apex:pageblocksection id="AddressInformationPBS" title="Address Information">
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:outputpanel >
                <apex:outputText style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;float:left;" value="Address Information"/>
                    <apex:commandLink style="Float:right;" value="Copy Billing Address To Shipping Address" action="{!copy_billingto_shipping}" reRender="AddressInformationPBS"/>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:facet>
             <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.BillingStreet}"></apex:inputfield>
             <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.ShippingStreet}"></apex:inputfield>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you able to provide some more details about what you're trying to do and what you have so far?

Comment: Isn't the style keys case sensitive. In your command link code you use `Float` when it should be `float`. Maybe an image of what you see vs what you want would help as well

Answer (score 2):

Style elements are case sensitive . You had "Float" instead of "float"

The below copied exactly works:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account"  tabstyle="Account">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock mode="edit" id="AccountPB" title="Account Edit">
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="Save"></apex:commandbutton>
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"></apex:commandbutton>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
    <apex:pageblocksection id="AddressInformationPBS" title="Address Information">
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:outputpanel >
                <apex:outputText style="font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;float:left;" value="Address Information"/>
                    <apex:commandLink style="float:right;" value="Copy Billing Address To Shipping Address"  reRender="AddressInformationPBS"/>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:facet>
             <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.BillingStreet}"></apex:inputfield>
             <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.ShippingStreet}"></apex:inputfield>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You will need to add back in you extension and the commandLink action when you put it back in your org

[image: Output]

Comment: Ugh, caught by the community bump an OP missing in action.....

Comment: No. It is still useful to me though I am not OP :) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:facet name="header">
        ... your html for links here ...
    </apex:facet>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Try to format your html like this. The `<facet name="header">` will replace the pageBlockSection Title content with whatever you place here. So in theory you can put your normal HTML header title left aligned and a link right aligned inside it.

A full working tested sample.

```
<apex:pageblock title="Page Block Title" mode="edit">
    <apex:pageblockSection>
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                  <td align="left"><h3>My Section Title</h3></td>
                  <td align="right">
                      <a href="javascript:alert('clicked here!!!');">Clickable Link</a>
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Comment: no sir its not working

Comment: hate to say it, but it does work, you just need to model your html around in the facet tag. I've edited my answer to include a full working sample.

Comment: Its at your convinient. You can replace standard html anchor links with visualforce <apex:commandLink> tags and add your function call to that commandLink action.